# Detect if Insert / update came from Another Trigger?

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have **table1** which is being updated and inserted with data via **sp's**.

the update is per Id of the row ( not bulk update) - I mean - `Single update`.

This table has Trigger **Tg1** - which updates some fields in the same record that has been updated . ( after the record updated in the db - TG1 update some of her fields)

```
I DONT HAVE ACCESS to TG1 !.
```

This table has another trigger which ive build **Tg2**.
which archive the original  inserted record via   `SELECT * FROM   DELETED ... and insert to table Archive...`

the problem is that **Tg2** catches `also` the events for **TG1** ! ( it inserting to the archive table 3 records insted of 1.

Question : Is there anyway (in **TG2**) to know that the Action came from **Tg1** ? ( so i would be able to avoid those events - since i need only the events which came from my sp.)

How can i solve that ? ( i dont have access to tg1...)

Comment: Your first problem is that trigger shoujld never be written on the assumption only one row will be inserted/deleted/changed.

Comment: @HLGEM , How can I solve it ?

Comment: To answer that qwuestion I would have to see the trigger tiself, However, you should not be setting anything to a scalar varaiable, use set-based statments instead.  And test with both a single record update and an update of multiple records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why would you not want to archive the record as it finally exists in the table?

However, you can set the trigger order on your trigger to be the first one using
**sp_settriggerorder**. Lookup in Books online how to do that.

Comment: Thank you very much i will search for the Order part. p.s. : the backup to another table is for versioning ... they need snapshots per time : `goto 1 year before - and tell me what the same record was looked like`....